# What is a good application for graphing vector spaces?

Tags: math-software

I am looking for a program to visualize vector spaces.  Ideally this is in the set of real numbers.  For instance what shape does the following vertex in $\Bbb R^3$ represent?
Vertices are: $\{(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,0)\}$

Comment: I believe it's a triangle in the $x-y$ plane...

Comment: Do you want to visualize vector spaces, or points in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Benjamin Lim, X3 is a free variable.

Comment: @utdiscant vector spaces in R3,  but if this program can't do points its useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pretty much anything for such a simple task. I give two examples of powerful and *free* software packages. One is [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org):

[image: scilab plot]

created with

```
points = [0 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 0]; // repeated endpoint to close the curve
param3d(points(:,1),points(:,2),points(:,3));  // creates the plot
p=get("hdl"); p.foreground=2; p.thickness=3;  // cosmetics: color and thickness
```

The actual plot (but not this illustration) can be rotated with a mouse to better visualize the position of the points in space.

But if you prefer something with simpler syntax, the [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) command

```
point([(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,0)])
```

does the job.